# Как установить dpi на мобильных устройствах, чтобы пиксель в css был ровно пикселем в устройстве?

Tags: html, css, css3, графика, веб-дизайн

Необходимо отобразить сайт на мобильном устройстве "как есть", точка-в-точку. Но не получается. С установкой мета-тегов, как я понял, все отталкивается от размеров viewport, а не от экрана устройства, и в результате все, что должно быть pixel-sharp получается чем-то размытым и лично меня сильно угнетает, а между блоками наблюдаются швы, которых быть не должно (самый неприятный момент).

Подскажите, кто знает, как сделать пиксель ровно пикселем, или хотя бы избежать швов между блоками? (без костылей, если можно)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

как показала практика самое оно для мобильных версий, размытость наверняка из-за картинок с маленьким разрешением.

а вот насчет швов, на ум приходит только inline блоки у которых после закрывающего тега и открывающего тега следующего блока стоит перенос на новую строку